# Site move to Rails - partials

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm moving my site to Rails currently.

Beforehand I used jQuery load() method to insert a separate site html element. Now moving to Rails, I have to change it. From what I've learnt so far, the best way here is to use a Rails partial for this purpose.
Is this correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you are correct. Partials come in handy when you want to load some HTML elements conditionally, or want to reuse them in different places. A prime example for that is the footer or header of a website. Instead of writing the code in all the required files, simply render the partial wherever required. For further reading/implementation guide, you can refer the [section on partials in the RoR guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials)

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend taking a read through the Ruby on Rails Guides which are extremely helpful if you are just getting started in Rails. The specific section that might help is their [documentation on using partials](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials).